# Remotely debugging service worker on chrome android with self signed certificate

Tags: android, google-chrome, certificate, remote-debugging, service-worker

I was trying to debug a service worker served from my dev machine and running inside chrome android on the smartphone.

I was using the usb connection and remotely debugging from my dev machine. The service worker works only in https and I can live with that, both chrome and firefox where refusing to register the SW.

Then I used a self signed certificate on my dev machine, which obviously was not trusted by the mobile browsers. They warned the certificate was not good but gave the option to proceed with that certificate. I clicked yes and, while firefox from that point was able to register the SW chrome was still compaining that the certificate was not good and refused to register the SW.

I tried to include the self signed CA in the smartphone trust list but didn't find a way to do that. In the end I had to serve the app from a production server with a regular certificate, which I didn't like at all, but I could not waste a whole day on this issue.

How is it possible to remote debug a service worker on android served from a dev machine in a LAN? localhost cannot be used because they are 2 separate devices. I found a setting to ignore the https waring for chrome but desktop version, I am using android chrome, how can I disable this boring blocking error?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, did you find an answer to this question ?

Comment: Actually, i just find : https://michielsioen.be/2019-11-23-the-pwa-experiment-pt2-debugging/