# Debug service worker with Chrome on Android mobile

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

I'm developing a progressive webapp and, in order to make sure it's working on mobile device (and particularly on Chrome for Android as it's 90% of users), I'm trying to test service worker on an Android device.

Unfortunaltely, on **Chrome for Android**, I'm **unable to register the service worker** :

> An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

---

I know service worker needs to be served over HTTPS so I have a *self-signed certificate* for my webapp. It is not trusted by browsers but it is still possible to proceed anyway. When using Firefox for Android, no problem I can sign to push notifications and register the service worker but **with Chrome it's not working**.

On Chrome for desktop, it's possible to enable service worker over non-secure origin with dev tools. I hoped to find the equivalent flag that I could use on mobile but none exists.

Is there a way to **authorize service worker on Chrome Android for debug purpose**?

---

I found an old question with no helpful answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331932/remotely-debugging-service-worker-on-chrome-android-with-self-signed-certificate) about the same issue and decided to open this one up for visibilty.

Comment: You can connect your desktop devtools to chrome on android and maybe it'll provide the same trick for enabling SW.

Comment: @wOxxOm sadly, I can't find a way to make it works this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the other StackOverflow post you're referring to, I can see the solution is in the question.

You need to **add a *Certificate Authority* crt to your Android trust list**.

---

**Why specifically a Certificate Authority .crt ?**

Simply because Android only accepts CA certificates.

---

**How do I get a CA certificate?**

Normally, a Certificate Authority (CA) acts as a trusted third party. For debug purpose, you can act as a CA to issue self-signed certificate yourself.

1. Create a root key: `openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 4096` (warning : anyone holding this can sign certificates on your behalf !)
2. Create and self sign the Root Certificate: `openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.crt`

Remember that your webapp's **SSL certificate needs to be generated with that same self-created CA**.

---

**Install certificate on Android device**

Once you got your .crt file, copy it inside your device. Then go to *Settings > Security > Install from storage*. It should detect the certificate and let you add it.

To make sure it's installed correctly, go to *Trusted Credentials* > *User*.

Comment: I add already created a CA certificate but thanks anyway for the explanation steps. I added it and it works !

Comment: I installed the self-trusted CA on my phone, but still getting insecure padlock warning.
I filed my steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503177/can-not-debug-service-worker-on-an-android-phone)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by portforwarding. You can find further info in my original answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56146180/5048121