# Can not debug service-worker on an Android phone

Tags: android, ssl, service-worker

I have a web app with service worker that is served from my Desktop, and I want to debug on an Android phone (Pixel3).
On the desktop I installed a self-trusted CA to satisfy the secured connection (https), and the page shows up with the secured padlock - good!.

**But on the phone, I cannot get the secured padlock to show up.**
(I can debug the web app by connecting the phone via USB cable, selecting *inspect* for the required tab, for the Pixel 3 XL device, in `chrome://inspect/#devices`, and interact with the page on Chrome on the phone and see the changes on the Desktop, but cannot get the secured padlock).

To satisfy the secured connection, I tried to do the following things:

- follow the instructions for [debugging on device](https://michielsioen.be/2019-11-23-the-pwa-experiment-pt2-debugging/)
- install the self-trusted CA on the phone using the instructions [here](https://aboutssl.org/how-to-create-and-import-self-signed-certificate-to-android-device/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911518/debug-service-worker-with-chrome-on-android-mobile)
  I installed the self-trusted CA myCA.pem (this is the same self-trusted CA that signs the web site certificate that is used on the Desktop, via `Security -> Install certificates -> myCA.pem`, and verified that it is installed in `Trusted credentials -> User -> myCA`)
- set up port forwarding in chrome devtools, and access the web site via *localhost* using instructions from [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160509/options-for-testing-service-workers-via-http/43426714#43426714).

  1. on chrome devtools I set port forwarding via `chrome://inspect/#devices -> port forwarding -> 8086 localhost:443`
  2. on the phone I set proxy via `Network and Internet -> Wi-Fi -> current network -> Proxy -> Manual -> Proxy hostname: localhost, Proxy port: 8086`
  3. on the phone I open the page [localhost:8086](http://localhost:8086), [https:\\localhost:8086](http://%3Cbr/%3E) (the page shows up with insecure padlock warning)
      **the page shows up with insecure padlock warning**
  4. (on the desktop https://localhost shows the secure padlock)
- set up port forwarding in chrome devtools, configure proxy settings on your device, map to custom local domains, and access the web site via custom domain: *mydomain*, following the instructions in [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server)

  1. on chrome devtools I set port forwarding via `chrome://inspect/#devices -> port forwarding -> 8086 mydomain:443`
  2. on the phone I set proxy via `Network and Internet -> Wi-Fi -> current network -> Proxy -> Manual -> Proxy hostname: localhost, Proxy port: 8086`
  3. on the phone I open the page [localhost:8086](http://mydomain:8086), [https:\\localhost:8086](http://https:%5C%5C%5C%5Clocalhost:8086)
      **the page shows up with insecure padlock warning**
  4. (on the desktop [https://mydomain](http://mydomain) shows the secure padlock)
- loosen the requirements for secured connection on the phone by setting:

  1. `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` to *Enabled*
  2. `chrome://flags/#insecure origins treated as secure` to *Enabled* with:
      `http://192.168.1.74, http://mydomain, http://localhost`
     (the flag `#insecure origins treated as secure` doesn't even help when running on the Desktop, and I'm getting an error like:
     `DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://192.168.1.74/') with script ('https://192.168.1.74/sw.js'): An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script`.

**None of these help. In the chrome tab on the phone I keep seeing the triangle icon for insecure connection.**

*Desktop:* Ubuntu 18.04, Chrome Version 83.0.4103.61
*Pixel 3 XL:* Chrome: 83.0.4103.106, Android version 10

Thanks
Avner

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remote debug the web app with the service worker, on the Android phone, by using, a combination of:

- web server configuration settings:

  - disable https
  - enable serving of http, with non standard port
  - disable redirect of http to https
- set the chrome flag: `Insecure origins treated as secure` in Chrome on the Desktop, and in the Android phone.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62567803/5159177) for details